# I have a conflict between my node version and firebase-functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I installed the latest version of firebase-functions, which is 4.2.1 and I'm running node version 19.6.0; however, when I set my node version in the package.json file, I'm getting an error when trying to run the firebase emulator that it wants version 10, 12, 14, or 16.  The error says: "functions: Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: package.json in functions directory has an engines field which is unsupported. Valid choices are: {"node": 10|12|14|16}"

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "19"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^11.5.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I've tried changing my node version in the package.json file to 16; however, I then get an error that says it was expecting node version 16 but got node version 19.6.0.  So I'm stuck at this point.

Comment: Can you try `"node" : ">=16"` or try downgrading `firebase-functions`?

Comment: Thank you, but the "node" : ">=16" didn't work. I could try to downgrade node to version 16, but that's a big difference between 16 and 19.

Comment: Have you tried downgrading `firebase-functions`?

Comment: @RoopaM firebase-functions is only supporting Node up to version 16 and I have node 19. Downgrading firebase-functions would only drop the level of version supported for Node. Downgrading Node to version 16 would/should resolve the issue, but I really don't want to downgrade 3 versions.

Comment: As per this [github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1450#issuecomment-629354102) issue specifying `runtime` in `firebase.json` would overwrite the `engines` specified in `package.json`.